# backbone.js: model.save() is always successful although it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I defined a model 'person' (and a collection 'persons') that has two fields - firstName and lastName. There is a view for creating persons and another view for editing existing persons. The only thing you can do with both views is to set the names. The responsible code looks like that:

**create view**

```
create: function () {
        var form = $(this.el).find("#add_form");
        this.model = window.persons.create({
            firstName: form.find("#firstname").val(),
            lastName: form.find("#lastname").val()
        }, {
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
            window.router.navigate("overview", {trigger: true});
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
        });
    }
```

**update view**

```
update: function () {
        var form = $(this.el).find("#edit_form");
        this.model.set({
            firstName: form.find("#firstname").val(),
            lastName: form.find("#lastname").val()
        });
        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function(){
                alert("success");
                window.router.navigate("overview", {trigger: true});
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

The model's **validaton logic**

```
validate: function(attrs) {
            var errors = [];
            if (!attrs.firstName || attrs.firstName.trim() === "") {
                errors.push({name: 'firstName', message: '...'});
            }
            if (!attrs.lastName || attrs.lastName.trim() === "") {
                errors.push({name: 'lastName', message: '...'});
            }
            //alert(errors.length);
            return errors.length > 0 ? errors : false;
        }
```

I'm using the localStorage module instead of a rest interface on a server.

Creating a model works as expected - I only can create a new person if there is a firstName and a lastName. In that case, the router forwards me to "overview". Otherwise, nothing happens (except the alert).

Unfortunetaly, editing persons always results in the success-callback, even if I set both names to an empty string. This means that I get forwarded by the router although it shouldn't happen. **BUT:** the model in the localStorage isn't updated in that case, so somehow the validation is working. The validation logic gets called four times when hitting the save button, the first time it returns an error-array with length > 0, the other three times it returns false.

Why do I always get the success-callback?

**edit:**

I updated backbone.js and underscore.js to the latest versions and the behavior changed. The success-callback doesn't get called anymore if there is no reason, but the error-callback isn't called either - it happens just nothing in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I misunderstood the error-callback; it **doesn't** get called if validation errors occur. The pattern looks like this:

```
model.save({
            // ...
        }, {
            success: function() {
                // gets called if EVERYTHING is okay
            },
            error: function() {
                // gets called if XHR errors or similar things occur
                // doesn't take validation errors into account
            }
        });
        if (this.model.validationError) {
            // this is for validation errors
        }
```

Comment: or to say it in other words: callbacks for success and error are no antagonists. In some cases, neither the success nor error-callback is called.

Answer (score 0):

use `isValid()` method. Run validate to check the model state.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validationError

Comment: thanks, of course this works, but I wanted to unterstand the problem I had. But I solved it (see answer).